# Query for SVM classifier : svmtrain function

Tags: matlab, classification, svm

I want to use `SVMStruct = svmtrain(Training,Group)` for two classes (**Noraml and Abnormal**) images classification purpose,and the size of the Training matrix is `1*40 cells` ,and each cell is `75 rows * 10 columns` so I want to give this Training matrix to the `svmtrain` function but after calling the `svmtrain` function I got this error :

> Error using svmtrain (line 241)
>   TRAINING must be a numeric matrix

Could anyone guide how to correct this error, because I am really stuck in that error, thank you.

The following are code lines what I tried :

```
clc

clear all;

close all;

%% After creating them in another section of code this section for loading two training matrices

load('norGlobal_matrix_train_variablek10bin25md.mat')

load('abGlobal_matrix_train_variablek10bin25md.mat')

counter_im=1;

[row ,col]=size(norGlobal_matrix_train_variablek10bin25md);

for i=1:10:row temp=norGlobal_matrix_train_variablek10bin25md(i:i+9,1:end);

    trasposed_temp=temp';
    normal_features {counter_im} =trasposed_temp;
    traininglabel{counter_im}=1 ; 
    counter_im=counter_im+1;
end

svm=svmtrain(normal_features{:}, traininglabel{:});
```

Comment: Do you need svm in images or data?